# Transformation of Normal Distribution to skew normal distribution

Tags: transformation, normal-distribution, skew

I have a set of data array which are almost like normal distribution. But I have to transform the data to a skew-normal distribution. After searching the internet, I figure out that any concave or convex bijective transformation will skew the normal distribution to the left or right.
I'm looking for the any papers or thesis or python code about above idea but i failed to find it.
Any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a scipy utility called `skewnorm` to produce skew-normal distribution. You can lookup the source on github, if required.

[External link to `scipy.stats.skewnorm` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html)